# Pass variable into run/debug configuration arguments

Tags: gulp, phpstorm, gulp-watch

I've done a fair old bit of searching, so asking here as a last resort!

I know under "File Watchers" there are variables/macros that can be passed into the arguments field like `$FileName$`

Can this be done with Run/Debug configurations? I've tested with the variables/macros available from File Watchers, but they just get passed directly through to my gulpfile.

If not possible, an alternate approach - is it possible to read the path that a watcher (gulp-watch) has been trigger from?

Many thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible. Generic support for using macros in run configurations was added in 2018.3 (see [IDEA-74031](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-74031)), but it has to be implemented separately for each configuration/field. Please feel free to file a request for adding variables support to Gulp run configuration to youtrack, https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB